# If I authenticate on a root domain, should www still work? vice versa? a different subdomain?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies

I have a legacy website with a very old codebase that I pretty much can't touch.  I am making version 2 and I want to make the old legacy version work on e.g.

```
classic.example.com
```

There are allot of users who might already be authenticated, and I don't want to force them to have to login again **i.e. ensure their existing cookie still work**

Using google chrome I can see the existing cookie, is there something I can look for to determine if the cookie will work?

Also, if I authenticate on www.example.com/login, should it work on example.com also?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the domain is set for the cookie. If it's set on example.com it will work on classic.example.com and www.example.com. If it's set on a subdomain, it won't work on other subdomain or the main domain.

Not sure about the last point of your question, but just to clarify, where you set the cookie and the domain you set don't need to be the same. You can be in a path under www.example.com and set a cookie for example.com. You need to use the optional "Domain" directive when you do Set-Cookie.